# PHP naming conventions?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

I'm coding smt right now, and am a little bit peeved by the fact that PHP sometimes calls its functions with underscore, and sometimes as one word. What's up with that?

Example:

> int strlen(string $str)

and

> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

I'm hoping that there is a good reason for this, and would really like to know what it is.

Comment: Is this a real question? I mean, can we really know without getting into a war?

Comment: It even has function names like `imagecreatefromgd2part` :) As well as mixed order of arguments for similar functions.

Comment: Welcome to the world of legacy. There's no answer to this question, only rants and flamewars. I'd say it's simply symptomatic of the language as a whole.

Comment: Well not having a convention is also a convention.

Comment: Question although interesting but subjective, and only result in arguments. Vote for close

Comment: i was hoping it can be avoided. i'm underestimating people's will to fight :). it's an interesting theme, though...

Comment: i was actually hoping to hear something like 'that is a result of big deal of people contributing or smt'. ok to close, though, if you feel like that

Comment: *"I don't know why people keep complaining about PHP's lack of convention when it has so many conventions to choose from!"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoted from: http://tnx.nl/php.html

> **PHP has inconsistent function naming**
>   There is no apparent system in underscore(s) versus no underscore(s):

```
underscore               no underscore:

stream_get_line          readline
disk_free_space          diskfreespace
is_object                isset
mcal_day_of_week         jddayofweek
set_error_handler        setlocale
snmp_get_quick_print     snmpget
get_browser              getallheaders
base64_encode            urlencode
image_type_to_mime_type  imagetypes
msql_num_fields          mysql_numfields
php_uname                phpversion
strip_tags               stripslashes
bind_textdomain_codeset  bindtextdomain
cal_to_jd                gregoriantojd
str_rot13                strpos
```

Comment: Thx anne... this is a winner :) although it is only badd comments, or they are prevailing there, at least. it served me well for quite a number of times, though.

Comment: Went through that list... Many statements are like 10 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to php. This has been a topic so many times.
Bottom line is, the only way to get over it is using a php centric ide/editor that suggests.
By the way that is just half the problem you will also see functions where the order is oposite.
Like

```
(mixed $needle , array $haystack)
```

and then

```
(array $haystack , string $needle)
```

So get used to it, or get out is the motto.

Comment: hahaha :)... yes, that one is a winner too. i'm coping with this pretty ok... i've been programming w php for a few years now... but this has been a puzzle for me all the way. and a source of frustration from time to time.

Comment: what about `implode(string $glue, array $pieces)` and `implode(array $pieces, string $glue)`? ;)